# Can't combine 'NOT IN' with CTE in a 'WHERE' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause, notin

**INPUT**: this is the `Order_Tbl` table with each row equivalent to a record of a transaction:

| ORDER_DAY | ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | QUANTITY | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-05-01 | ODR1 | PROD1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2015-05-01 | ODR2 | PROD2 | 2 | 10 |
| 2015-05-01 | ODR3 | PROD3 | 10 | 25 |
| 2015-05-01 | ODR4 | PROD1 | 20 | 5 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR5 | PROD3 | 5 | 25 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR6 | PROD4 | 6 | 20 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR7 | PROD1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR8 | PROD5 | 1 | 50 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR9 | PROD6 | 2 | 50 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR10 | PROD2 | 4 | 10 |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**: the task is to write a T-SQL query to get products that was ordered on `02-May-2015` but not on any other days before that:

| ORDER_DAY | ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | QUANTITY | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR6 | PROD4 | 6 | 20 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR8 | PROD5 | 1 | 50 |
| 2015-05-02 | ODR9 | PROD6 | 2 | 50 |

I did try 2 solutions with a same approach: using a (completely identical) subquery to get a list of distinct products that were ordered before `02-May-2015`, and then somehow putting it after the `NOT IN` operator inside the `WHERE` clause of the main query.

Solution 1: the subquery was passed in as an `CTE`. It throws a syntax error ...

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID
    FROM Order_Tbl
    WHERE ORDER_DAY < '2015-05-02'
)
SELECT *
FROM Order_Tbl
WHERE ORDER_DAY = '2015-05-02'
  AND PRODUCT_ID NOT IN CTE
```

Solution 2: the subquery was embedded into the `WHERE` clause of the main query. This worked!

```
SELECT *
FROM Order_Tbl
WHERE ORDER_DAY = '2015-05-02'
  AND PRODUCT_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID
                         FROM Order_Tbl
                         WHERE ORDER_DAY < '2015-05-02')
```

What was the nuance that made SQL behave and return different results? I would appreciate it if you guys could give me a clear explanation as well as some useful notes for further SQL implementations.

Comment: You seem to believe you can write SQL like C# or something; `(NOT) IN {Table Name|Table Alias|CTE Name}` simply isn't valid syntax. A `(NOT) IN` expects either a list of scalar values or a subquery, both of which should go in parentheses.

Comment: You did never use the CTE. (It's expected to be found in a FROM clause. E.g. something similar to `where PRODUCT_ID not in (select PRODUCT_ID from CTE)`.)

Comment: @jarlh you can define a CTE and *not* use it in the following statement. *Why* you'd do that, I've no idea, but you *can*.

Comment: @ThomA, I know. But I do expect someone defining a cte to also use it.

Comment: As a side note, generally I avoid `NOT IN`, especially when using a subquery. `NOT IN` can result in (documented) behaviour that some users don't expect when dealing with `NULL` values. `NOT EXISTS` is often a "better" solution.

Comment: Also `DISTINCT` is pointless in an `IN` or `EXISTS` subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The task is to write a T-SQL query to get products that was ordered on 02-May-2015 but not on any other days before that

It has been explained by Thom A in the comments that [`NOT IN` does not accept the first syntax you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76218250/cant-combine-not-in-with-cte-in-a-where-clause/76219207#comment134409639_76218250), and that, even with the right syntax, [`NOT EXISTS` is in general preferable to `NOT IN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76218250/cant-combine-not-in-with-cte-in-a-where-clause/76219207#comment134409781_76218250):

```
select *
from order_tbl o
where order_day = '2015-05-02'
  and not exists (
    select 1 
    from order_tbl o1 
    where o1.product_id = o.product_id and o1.order_day < o.order_day 
)
```

The query ensures that there is no row in the table for the same product and an erlier order date. For performance, consider an index on `order_tbl(product_id, order_day)`.

But overall, it is probably simpler and more efficient to use window functions ; the subquery can just be replaced with a window `min()`:

```
select *
from (
    select o.*, min(order_day) over(partition by product_id) min_order_day
    from order_tbl o
) o
where order_day = '2015-05-02' and min_order_day = order_day
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, CTE A CTE allows you to define a temporary named result set that available temporarily, you should treat it like a table and query and write your code in this way

```
select *
from Order_Tbl
where ORDER_DAY = '2015-05-02'
    and PRODUCT_ID not in (
        select distinct PRODUCT_ID
        from Order_Tbl
        where ORDER_DAY < '2015-05-02'
        )
```

[Cte](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/common-table-expression-cte-in-sql-server/)